# What's the better solution for this javascript code not using reverse method

Tags: javascript

I'm trying that this code works but not success and I need help to find out where is the mistake to make it works. I don't want to use reverse method which will be a better and fast solution but to find the other way, It's challenge for me. Any instructions how to solve this problem? Any input will be welcomed.

Thanks

```
    <body>
    <form id="form_id">
       <input type="text" id="your_input" />
    </form>
    <script>
        isPalindrome = function() {
            var len = this.length-1;
                for (var i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
                    if (this.charAt(i) !== this.charAt(len-i)) {
                    return false;
                    }
                }
                else if (i === (len-i)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return true;
            }

            document.getElementById("form_id").onsubmit = function() {
               isPalindrome(document.getElementById('your_input').value);
                return false;
            }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code you posted has a syntax error: the else statement is following the for loop. Did you copy your code correctly?

Comment: Please check parenthesis once.

Comment: Do you see _any_ error in console? As pointed out above, there should be at least one.

Comment: On submit, you are calling that function, but don't do anything with its result? What did you expect? Also, what did you do (enter input) that lead to "no success"?

Comment: Thanks for the input, yes the else is misplaced and to find the curly bracket I will rewrite again the code.

Comment: None errors in the console. Exactly, Bergi, It doesn't anything. What I expect that after write a palindrome word in the input, the code confirms if the word is in fact a palindrome or not palindrome. I took away else already.